# Recognize blowing or clapping hands with microphone sensor(Arduino Uno)

Tags: arduino, dsp, arduino-uno

I want to recognize between blowing or clapping hands with microphone sensor(Arduino Uno) and than with DSP to know which gesture is made.

I took a lot of samples but when clapping there is no difference on the output values on arduino(the same like there is silent).

thank you.

Comment: I wish you good luck with your project. Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, how to recognize between the two gestures?

Comment: Trial and error method ? By analysing and studying the amplitude and time duration of different gestures.

Comment: Get a microphone and a PC and set up a test using some free wave analysis tool. This is the wrong site for asking how to recognize between the two gestures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not EE.

Comment: Big data claims to handle any signal discrimination challenge. Gather lots of data, many claps, many people clapping. And many blowing. Then provide a neural-system and train it.

Comment: You can make a 'clap' detector out of slow-clocked shift registers and comparators based on input volume, band-pass filters and timing.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you cannot check frequencies, so the only way to check is with the amplitude (volume) over time.

A handclap reaches very fast a high volume, and afterwards decreases very fast.

A blow can be more various, if you give a very short/hard blow it might be similar.

So you have to check against 'profiles' and the one (blow or handclap) which matches should be assumed to use.

To make it more difficult, hand claps can vary also in length if there is reverb/eche. Also background noise can be a problem.

Comment: so how can I distinguish between this two gestures using DSP if the sampled frequencies of both are very similar? Can I filter the values such  that i get some frequency threshhold (using convolution) with which it can be possible to destinguish between the gestures  - do you think this is not possible?

Comment: I don't know if you can use frequency. But if you know the volumes over time, than a handclap is short and 'immediately' at max volume and when the clap ends 'immediately' back to volume 0, while a blow is normally slower to begin and slower to end (slower attach/decay). I don't know if you need a DSP for this... on the other hand, there might be many more sounds that will be treated similar as a handclap or blow.

Comment: I must use DSP...
but how can I get the values of volume from arduino smaples?

Comment: With the 'typical sound' sensor you get an analog input which you can sample yourself. The Arduino should be fast enough to do some simple calculations. See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Knock ... but you have to sample to 'calculate' differences in profiles .